# What does this Python default argument syntax do?

Tags: python, syntax, default

I've been searching around for quite a while, and I cannot for the life of me figure out what the following function definition does:

```
class ImageManager:
    # Unimportant Stuff

def image_draw(master, items=4, drawer: ImageManager = None, **kwargs):
    # More Code
```

Just to be clear, I'm wondering about the syntax of the default argument `drawer` in the function `image_draw`. It appears to provide a default value for an argument, but why does it set a same-scope classname to `None`? Why not just `drawer=None`? It just doesn't make sense to me at the moment.

This code is for an internal system that my job is to improve.

Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: `drawer: ImageManager` = Type hint.

Comment: `ImageManager` is the required [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) and `None` is the default value.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thank you! I just needed to know those key words.